# Using Calendar in java. Getting a compilation error of cannot find symbol

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I am getting error for cannot find symbol

`getInstance(),Calendar.DATE,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.YEAR`

This only occurs when I am running offline on VS Code. 
    On running in on an online IDE (Hacker Rank), I get compilation successful.
    JDK 11 on desktop, JDK 8 on Hacker Rank.
    I have tried running it on multiple IDEs and get compilation successful only on JDK 8

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Calendar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        int year = sc.nextInt();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        System.out.println(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, new Locale("en", "US")).toUpperCase());
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. For your use you probably need  `LocalDate`  from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead: `LocalDate.of(year, month, day)`.

Comment: By *VS* do you mean Visual Studio?? Could you show us your import statement?

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimum that still reproduces the error and then include full source code? It sounds a lot like you're missing an import but can't be sure.

Comment: Don't name your class `Calendar` when you what do use `java.util.Calendar`!

Comment: Easy and modern way: `System.out.println(LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek());`. Prints for example `SUNDAY`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have named your class Calendar, and then are trying to use a system class named Calendar.  Calling Calendar.getInstance() is failing to compile because the compiler is looking for a method named getInstance() to be defined in YOUR Calendar class.  Name your class something else, and I think your code will compile and work fine.

Comment: Also calling the Java until class with full name will work, like so: `java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(); ...`